# Converting a string into seperate integers and calculating mean

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to create a program that calculates the mean of a series of numbers that the user enters. Here is my code so far, I believe that the problem lies with the map function.

```
    rawnumbers = input("Enter a series of numbers\n :")
    Numbers = map(int,rawnumbers.split());

    def Mean():
    sumcount = 0
    Mean = 0
    for num in Numbers:
        sumcount = sumcount+num
        Mean = Mean / len(Numbers)
        return Mean
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
"TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()"
```

Comment: Simple answer, use `list` call there.  `Numbers = list(map(int,rawnumbers.split()))`

Comment: Thanks, but the mean function doesnt work now. The mean is 0.0 when I entered 4, 5 and 6

Comment: Thanks, it works now

Comment: Oh Ok. Glad to hear that. All the best